# Trying to add a link to open a 'steam://run/' link to a random word array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables, hyperlink

So i'm messing about creating a random word picker to pick a steam game from my library, I want to add a 'Launch' link to each random word. Heres the code;

```
    <html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="steam_gen_style.css">

     <title>Untitled</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
// Use the following variable to specify
// the number of random words
var NumberOfWords = 28

var words = new BuildArray(NumberOfWords)

// Use the following variables to
// define your random words:
words[1] = "ARK: Survival Evolved/346110"
words[2] = "Portal 2/620"
words[3] = "Left 4 Dead 2/550"
words[4] = "CS:GO/730"
words[5] = "And Yet It Moves/18700"
words[6] = "Bridge Constructer/250460"
words[7] = "Bridge Constructer Medieval/319850"
words[8] = "Half-Life 2/220"
words[9] = "GTA V/271590"
words[10] = "Antichamber/219890"
words[11] = "World of Goo/22000"
words[12] = "Super meat Boy/40800"
words[13] = "Hotline Miami/219150"
words[14] = "Metro: Last Light/287390"
words[15] = "GTA IV/12210"
words[16] = "Oddworld: New'n'Tasty/314660"
words[17] = "TUG"
words[18] = "Trials Evo"
words[19] = "Super Hotline Miami"
words[20] = "Outlast"
words[21] = "Besiege"
words[22] = "Next Car Game"
words[23] = "Rust"
words[24] = "Garry's Mod"
words[25] = "Planetary Annihilation"
words[26] = "Skyrim"
words[27] = "Minecraft"
words[28] = "The Forest"


function BuildArray(size){
this.length = size
for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++){
this[i] = null}
return this
}

function PickRandomWord(frm) {
var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfWords);

var index = words[rnd].indexOf("/");

frm.WordBox.value = words[rnd].substring(0, index);
var link = document.getElementById("gameLink");
var str = words[rnd].substring(index + 1, words[rnd].length);
link.innerHTML = "<a href='steam://run/" + str + "'>Click</a>";
}

// Display the word inside the text box
frm.WordBox.value = words[rnd]
}
//-->

</SCRIPT>

<body>
  <div id="top"></div>
<header id="header">
  <h1> Today you will play </h1>

  <FORM NAME="WordForm" id="box">
    <INPUT



TYPE=TEXT SIZE=30 NAME="WordBox" id="output"><BR>
    <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON id="button" onClick="PickRandomWord(document.WordForm)"
VALUE="Click Here to Get a Random Word">  

</FORM>
<p>Link to game: </p>
<p id="gameLink"></p>

</header>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a few things but stuck, by the way, I've never done anything with java I only know a little bit of HTMl, I'm just messing around to learn things!

Comment: so you want to generate a random number between 1 to 28 that select that position in array?

Comment: So basically, it generates one of those words at random when I click a button, but I want to add a link to each word so when the random word becomes generated, it has a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want a link to be generated based on the game selected you can add below 2 lines at the end of `PickRandomWord()`,

```
 var link = document.getElementById("gameLink");
 link.innerHTML = "<a href='steam://run/'"+words[rnd]+">"+words[rnd]+"</a>";
```

Now add 2 more HTML lines after you form,

```
<p>Link to game: </p>
<p id="gameLink"></p>
```

**UPDATE:** You need to have the numbers like 346110, 620 to be stored somewhere so that you can access them depending on the game you select. As you asked for an example, here is what I have come up with.

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/62L94juc/1/)

Suppose you append the numbers along with the name of the game as,

```
 words[1] = "ARK: Survival Evolved/346110";
 words[2] = "Portal 2/620";
```

Now change your `PickRandomWord()` function as,

```
    function PickRandomWord(frm) {
        var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfWords);

        var index = words[rnd].indexOf("/");

        frm.WordBox.value = words[rnd].substring(0, index);
        var link = document.getElementById("gameLink");
        var str = words[rnd].substring(index + 1, words[rnd].length);
        link.innerHTML = "<a href='steam://run/" + str + "'>Click</a>";
    }
```

**UPDATE2:** You are having problems with your parenthesis and it is not advisable to write JavaScript statements without semi-colon(;). Copy and paste the below code as it is,

```
<script>
    var NumberOfWords = 28

    var words = new BuildArray(NumberOfWords)

    words[1] = "ARK: Survival Evolved/346110"
    words[2] = "Portal 2/620"
    words[3] = "Left 4 Dead 2/621"
    words[4] = "CS:GO/622"
    words[5] = "And Yet It Moves/622"
    words[6] = "Bridge Constructer/6203"
    words[7] = "Bridge Constructer Medieval/6520"
    words[8] = "Half-Life 2/6290"
    words[9] = "GTA V/6020"
    words[10] = "Antichamber/6250"
    words[11] = "World of Goo/6820"
    words[12] = "Super meat Boy/6290"
    words[13] = "Hotline Miami/61020"
    words[14] = "Metro: Last Light/62110"
    words[15] = "GTA IV/67620"
    words[16] = "Oddworld: New'n'Tasty/62870"
    words[17] = "TUG/687820"
    words[18] = "Trials Evo/6120"
    words[19] = "Super Hotline Miami/60"
    words[20] = "Outlast/690"
    words[21] = "Besiege/62900"
    words[22] = "Next Car Game/62023"
    words[23] = "Rust/620879"
    words[24] = "Garry's Mod/626750"
    words[25] = "Planetary Annihilation/6260"
    words[26] = "Skyrim/6276870"
    words[27] = "Minecraft/656520"
    words[28] = "The Forest/5620"

    function BuildArray(size) {
        this.length = size
        for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            this[i] = null
        }
        return this
    }

    function PickRandomWord(frm) {
        var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfWords);

        var index = words[rnd].indexOf("/");

        frm.WordBox.value = words[rnd].substring(0, index);
        var link = document.getElementById("gameLink");
        var str = words[rnd].substring(index + 1, words[rnd].length);
        link.innerHTML = "<a href='steam://run/" + str + "'>Click</a>";
    }
</SCRIPT>
<body>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <header id="header">
         <h1> Today you will play the shit out of </h1>

        <FORM NAME="WordForm" id="box">
            <INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=30 NAME="WordBox" id="output">
            <BR>
            <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON id="button" onClick="PickRandomWord(document.WordForm)" VALUE="Click Here to Get a Random Word">
        </form>
        <p>Link to game:</p>
        <p id="gameLink"></p>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes it so all the games have the same link, how can I make each game have a different link when it's picked?

Comment: @user5006419 Where are the link for each game is stored?

Comment: I haven't got any stored at the moment, I was hoping to ad 

    "href="steam://run/"

then the id of each game, which would launch an external protocol request? Or if that doesn't work just a link to the games webpage.

Comment: @user5006419 check out my updated answer, I have changes href atribute is this what you mean?

Comment: hmm still not working, so for example words[1] = "ARK: Survival Evolved" would need to link to steam://run/346110 

Whereas, words[2] = "Portal 2" would need to link to steam://run/620.

So how would I make it so each game links to a separate link? Sorry if I'm not being clear!

Comment: @user5006419 you should be having "346110" for "ARK: Survival Evolved", 620 for "Portal 2" to be stored somewhere to access it

Comment: hmmm ok I'm not sure how to do that, I'll look it up

Comment: would you be able to give me an example, i'm not too sure what you mean by store it, I'm a bit stuck here!

Comment: @user5006419 check my updated answer and the link that I have given. Tell me if this helps

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, it doesn't output anything, I've updated my code if you want to look

Comment: @user5006419 did you checked my fiddle? The output is displayed in it.

Comment: @user5006419 check my update 2, You have not written numbers(Eg: 620) for every game. Moreover, you had problems with the parenthesis and it is not advisable to ignore  semi-colon (;) forJavaScript statements

Comment: @user5006419 I tried this code and it works fine for me too, you should accept this answer to encourage people to answer your questions in future or ask your doubt about it

Comment: @user5006419 click on  the tick mark which will turn green when you click it